# I can't change the value of a struct variable within a slice in Go

Tags: go

this my code is run, but when I m trying change the valeu of slice into atribute count , this value doesn't change.

I change values ip because they are internal. How I say this code is run, He have more others functions that send emails but they don't make problems.

```
func testeLink() {
    naves := []nave{
        nave{"SC", "111.11.11.111", 0},
        nave{"MA", "222.2.222.2", 0},
        nave{"PE", "333.33.33.33", 0}}

    sliceLength := len(naves)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(sliceLength)

    for i := range naves {
        go func(nave nave) {

            out, _ := exec.Command("ping", nave.ip, "-c 1 -w 1").Output()
            //out, _ := exec.Command("ping", "192.168.0.111", "-c 1", "-i 3", "-w 10").Output()
            if strings.Contains(string(out), "0 received") || strings.Contains(string(out), "Received = 0") {
                fmt.Print(naves[i].count)
                nave.count++

                fmt.Print(nave.count)
                fmt.Printf("A nave <%s> está OFFline \n", nave.name)

                if nave.count >= 3 {
                    enviarEmail(nave.name)
                }
            } else {
                nave.count = 0
                fmt.Printf("A nave <%s> está ONline \n", nave.name)

            }
            defer wg.Done()
        }(naves[i])

    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {

    for {
        testeLink()
        fmt.Println("Aguardando o tempo ...")
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the copying of values, you can't combine multiple arguments in a single string, so `"-c 1 -w 1"` is probably not doing what you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goroutine is taking `naves[i]` by value, so a copy of it is being passed to it. Pass a reference to it:

```
go func(nave *nave) {...} (&naves[i])
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass `i`:

```
go func(i int) { // use naves[i] in the goroutine } (i)
```

Comment: For me the value of atribute count in each interaction continue with "1"

Comment: Check your algorithm. You redeclare the array every time the function runs. `nave.count` can never be larger than 1 the way it is written.

Comment: I'm sorry I was even embarrassed. Thank you !!!!!!!!